# Java: Determine logical font from a font name

Tags: java, fonts

I'm working on a RESTful service in Java.  Part of this is to take data that is stored in a database that contains a font name (e.g. Arial) and return JSON beans to a client that contains not only the font name to use, but the logical font that it belongs to (e.g. serif, monospace, etc...).

I've looked at using the java.awt.Font class to try and get this information, but when i call getName(), I always only ever get back the original font name (Arial).  What I want is to get the logical font that this font belongs to (Sans-Serif).

Here is an example of what I've tried:

```
    Font[] tfonts;
    tfonts = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts();
    for (int i = 0; i < tfonts.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(tfonts[i].getFontName() + " : ");
      System.out.print(tfonts[i].getFamily() + " : ");
      System.out.print(tfonts[i].getName());
      System.out.println();
    }
```

The output of this is basically:

```
Times New Roman : Times New Roman : Times New Roman
```

It is surprising that the root logical font is not found anywhere here.  I was hoping to see Serif in here somewhere.  I've even tried inspecting the output of the getAttributes() call, and don't see this information there.

The reason I want to do this, we have data objects that contain a field of display fonts that were created from fonts available on a user's PC.  We are sending these objects to other platforms (namely iOS) where these fonts may not actually exist.  What I'd like to do is send "Serif" or something in its place, and let the iOS clients pick a suitable Serif font.   But I cannot seem to find a way to get back to the logical font for a given named font.

I appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Build a Map with the font name and the font type (serif, sans-serif, and monospace).

Comment: The problem is I have no idea what fonts could be stored in the data, so I cannot build a map to just pull that information from.  I suppose I could build a huge map with hundreds of potential fonts in there and do this, but that seems unnecessary. I was hoping that using the right Java classes/methods I could get that information from the font files themselves.  Thanks.

Comment: The Java Font class has protected and private fields that probably contain the information you need, but can't get.  Your alternative is to build your own Map with a general default, perhaps sans-serif.